# Extracting individual data from a string

Tags: javascript

Snippet of code doesnt work properly:

```
<script>
var singledata = [];
var txt = "141112,15:00,22.5\n141112,16:00,22.6\n141112,17:00,22.7\n";
var lines = txt.split("\n");
for (var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
   singledata.push( [lines.split(',')] );
}
console.log(lines);
console.log(singledata[0]);
</script>
```

the txt string will normally come from a text file

I would like to get an array with following data:

```
singledata = [[141112,15:00,22.5],[141112,16:00,22.6],[141112,17:00,22.7]];
```

This is an example normally the data file could contain > 1000 lines.
So i would like to avoid having to use an array for the lines and then
another one with the same data but split up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
singledata.push( lines[i].split(',') );
```

`lines` is the whole array, `lines[i]` is the current element in the iteration.

You don't need `[]` around `lines[i].split(',')`. `split` returns an array, you were wrapping another around around it for no reason.

```js
var singledata = [];
var txt = "141112,15:00,22.5\n141112,16:00,22.6\n141112,17:00,22.7\n";
var lines = txt.split("\n");
for (var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
   singledata.push( lines[i].split(',') );
}
console.log(lines);
console.log(singledata[0]);
```

Comment: Can I ask why the `[]` brackets are needed here? (i don't mean these ones - `lines[i]` but these - `...push([])` I think it should work this way: `sdata.push(lines[i].split(','))`

Comment: They're not, I just copied that from his code without even noticing it.

Comment: I use 2 arrays for this both containing the same data but organized in a different way , doubling the memory requirement.Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: You can have multiple arrays or objects that refer to the same sub-objects or sub-arrays, but in different orders or different properties.

Comment: Do you mean the memory usage is not doubled?

Comment: No, because the two arrays contain references to the same objects, not copies.